# Busy wait, sleep and accuracy

Tags: java, optimization

I am now attempting to write simple renderer that will call render method at 60Hz and sleep the extra time to save CPU cycles for someone else.

I encountered one simple problem with following

```
while(m_Running){
    //start meassuring whole frame time
    t0 = System.nanoTime();

    render();

    //meassure time spent rendering
    t1 = System.nanoTime();

    if(t1<nextRedraw){
        try{
            diff = nextRedraw-t1;
            ms = diff/1000000;
            ns = (int) (diff-(ms*1000000));
            Thread.sleep(ms, ns);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Logger.logWarning("Renderer interrupted!",e);
        }
        //while(System.nanoTime()<nextRedraw);//busy wait alternative
    }

    //meassure time spent sleeping
    t2 = System.nanoTime();
    nextRedraw = t2+m_RedrawTimeout;

    long frameTime = t2-t0;
    long renderTime = t1-t0;
    long sleepTime = t2-t1;
    long fps = 1000000000/frameTime;
}
```

which runs fine, but far from intended 60fps, but instead it is jumping around values

```
FPS: 63 Frame: 15,7ms   Render: 2,0ms   Sleep: 13,7ms
FPS: 64 Frame: 15,5ms   Render: 2,0ms   Sleep: 13,5ms
FPS: 63 Frame: 15,7ms   Render: 2,1ms   Sleep: 13,5ms
FPS: 59 Frame: 16,7ms   Render: 2,8ms   Sleep: 14,0ms
FPS: 64 Frame: 15,5ms   Render: 2,2ms   Sleep: 13,3ms
```

When I try using busy wait instead, result is much more consistent and closer to my desired fps target.

```
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,4ms   Render: 2,0ms   Sleep: 14,5ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,4ms   Render: 2,0ms   Sleep: 14,4ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,4ms   Render: 2,0ms   Sleep: 14,4ms
FPS: 61 Frame: 16,3ms   Render: 2,4ms   Sleep: 13,8ms
FPS: 61 Frame: 16,3ms   Render: 2,1ms   Sleep: 14,2ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,4ms   Render: 2,0ms   Sleep: 14,4ms
```

I would like to avoid that though, for understandable CPU drawback. I got an idea of sleeping bit less than necessary and looping through the remaining time to be precise but that seems a bit clunky.

My question is, whether is busy wait somehow optimized by compiler, or if there is some other way to hit similar timing?

Any help would be appreciated.

With kind regards,

Vojtěch

NOTE: I used System.nanoTime(); in attempt to make things more accurate, it did not help but I'm not aware of any performance drawbacks on it

NOTE: I know that sleep is pretty inaccurate but I did not find any other alternative

Comment: Is your computer otherwise busy? One thing that comes to mind is that a `Thread.sleep`'s wakeup is at the mercy of the thread scheduler to a greater degree than a busy-wait loop. Technically the scheduler can do whatever it wants to either thread, but it could be that it's unlikely to park an active thread for very long, whereas it's more lax about respecting a thread's scheduled wakeup request.

Comment: Not at all actually, not to mention I'm running right now on quad core i7 which should have quite merciful sheduler at pretty much idle state. It must be somehow possible considering big games do have FPS cap, often strictly followed. Just is that available in java?

Comment: Have you considered using a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for managing the timing?

Comment: From the javadocs: *sleep(long millis) Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, **subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers**.* Never rely on it for timing in production code! Use ScheduledExecutorService as suggested by @Steve C or smarter custom timing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went through suggestions and tested these three variants on top of previously posted code:

#### ScheduledExecutorService

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler 
    = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

//handle for killing the process
private ScheduledFuture<?> handle = null;

//meassuring actual time between redraws
private long lastRenderStart = 0;

//start will fire off new scheduler at desired 60Hz
@Override
public synchronized void start() {
    handle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 
        100000000, m_RedrawTimeout, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}

public void kill(){
    if(handle!=null){
        handle.cancel(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void run(){
    //meassured render routine
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    render();
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.format("render time %.1fms\t\tframe time %.1fms\n",
        ((t1-t0)/1000000.0d),
        ((t0-lastRenderStart)/1000000.0d));
    lastRenderStart = t0;
}
```

This made code somehow simpler and AFAIK did not introduce any overhead, but precision is still not at the point I wanted it

```
render time 1,4ms       frame time 17,0ms
render time 1,4ms       frame time 16,0ms
render time 1,7ms       frame time 17,0ms
render time 1,3ms       frame time 17,0ms
render time 1,8ms       frame time 16,0ms
render time 14,8ms      frame time 16,9ms
render time 2,0ms       frame time 17,0ms
```

#### Aligned loop

```
    long nextRedraw,baseTime = System.nanoTime();
    m_Running=true;
    for (long i=0; m_Running; ++i) {
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        render();
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();

        nextRedraw = baseTime + i * m_RedrawTimeout;

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        if(now<nextRedraw){
            try{
                Thread.sleep((nextRedraw-now)/1000000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                Logger.logWarning("Renderer interrupted!",e);
            }
        }

        long t2 = System.nanoTime();

        long frameTime = t2-t0;
        long renderTime = t1-t0;
        long sleepTime = t2-t1;
        long fps = 1000000000/frameTime;
        System.out.format("FPS: %d\tFrame: %3.1fms\t"
            +"Render: %3.1fms\tSleep: %3.1fms\n", 
            fps, frameTime/1000000.0, renderTime/1000000.0, sleepTime/1000000.0);
    }
```

This approach holds frame time around 16.67 ms more often than not, and seems bit more elegant that originally posted code, but there are still peaks shorter by 1ms (for whatever reason, maybe rounding in system scheduler?)

```
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,6ms   Render: 1,7ms   Sleep: 14,9ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,6ms   Render: 1,8ms   Sleep: 14,8ms
FPS: 63 Frame: 15,7ms   Render: 2,3ms   Sleep: 13,4ms
FPS: 59 Frame: 16,7ms   Render: 1,8ms   Sleep: 14,8ms
FPS: 63 Frame: 15,6ms   Render: 2,0ms   Sleep: 13,7ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,7ms   Render: 1,9ms   Sleep: 14,7ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,6ms   Render: 1,9ms   Sleep: 14,7ms
FPS: 59 Frame: 16,8ms   Render: 1,8ms   Sleep: 15,0ms
FPS: 64 Frame: 15,6ms   Render: 1,9ms   Sleep: 13,7ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,6ms   Render: 1,9ms   Sleep: 14,7ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,6ms   Render: 1,8ms   Sleep: 14,8ms
```

#### Aligned loop with busy wait segment

In this I tried to add busy wait segment into loop to wait out remaining time after sleeping the thread to precise framerate.

```
    long nextRedraw,baseTime = System.nanoTime();
    m_Running=true;
    for (long i=0; m_Running; ++i) {
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        render();
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();

        nextRedraw = baseTime + i * m_RedrawTimeout;

        if(t1<nextRedraw){
            //if sleepy time is bigger than 1ms, use Thread.sleep
            if(nextRedraw-t1>1000000){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(((nextRedraw-t1-1000000)/1000000));
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    Logger.logWarning("Renderer interrupted!",e);
                }
            }
            t2 = System.nanoTime();
            //do busy wait on last ms or so
            while(System.nanoTime()<nextRedraw);
        }

        long t3 = System.nanoTime();

        long frameTime = t3-t0;
        long renderTime = t1-t0;
        long sleepTime = t2-t1;
        long busyWaitTime = t3-t2;
        long fps = 1000000000/frameTime;
        System.out.format("FPS: %d\tFrame: %3.1fms\t"
                + "Render: %3.1fms\tSleep: %3.1fms\tBusyW: %3.1fms\n", 
                fps, frameTime/1000000.0, renderTime/1000000.0, 
                sleepTime/1000000.0,busyWaitTime/1000000.0);
    }
```

It looks bit messy, sorry for that, but in exchange of about of 2ms of CPU time of busy wait I got pretty steady timing on 60FPS.

```
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,5ms   Render: 1,5ms   Sleep: 13,8ms   BusyW: 1,2ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,5ms   Render: 1,4ms   Sleep: 13,2ms   BusyW: 1,8ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,4ms   Render: 1,6ms   Sleep: 12,4ms   BusyW: 2,5ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,5ms   Render: 1,2ms   Sleep: 13,1ms   BusyW: 2,1ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,5ms   Render: 1,4ms   Sleep: 13,3ms   BusyW: 1,8ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,4ms   Render: 1,4ms   Sleep: 12,5ms   BusyW: 2,5ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,5ms   Render: 1,2ms   Sleep: 13,1ms   BusyW: 2,2ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,5ms   Render: 1,3ms   Sleep: 13,4ms   BusyW: 1,8ms
FPS: 60 Frame: 16,4ms   Render: 1,5ms   Sleep: 12,5ms   BusyW: 2,5ms
```

So thanks everyone for suggestions, hope this helps someone at some point :)

With kind regards,

Vojtěch

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the small variances in timing may add up to a greater amount and you can easily avoid it by making the sleep dependent on the total time.

Something like

```
long basetime = System.nanoTime();
for (int i=0; m_Running; ++i) {
    ...
    nextRedraw = baseTime + i * m_RedrawTimeout;
}
```

This should make a following sleep shorter if the current one was too short and vice versa, so you get an FPS varying only by at most a few ms per second (i.e., < 1%).

---

And maybe there's no problem, it's just that what you measure is how long a single frame takes. This number varies a bit and doesn't say much about the FPS rate.

AFAIK the nanoseconds in `Thread.sleep` get completely ignored.

Comment: Didn't know about nanoseconds being ignored. Kind of misleading javadoc on oracle part then. You should not have to check someone elses implementation whether it does what the javadoc says it does. Thanks, will test your approach and ScheduledExecutorService suggested by @Steve C and report the result.

Comment: @VojtěchKaiser I guess, `Thread.sleep` should honor the nanos, it's just that no OS seems to support it. The key is *"subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers"*, which says "undefined". In my sources, I see that nanos are not completely ignored, but the time gets rounded to full millis and `sleep(millis)` gets called. The `ScheduledExecutorService` might do exactly what you want and then it's a good idea. If you want some more flexibility, it'd be easier to run your own (you're nearly done already). I'm pretty sure, both will work fine.